# How do I test services in polymer?

Tags: unit-testing, polymer, mocha.js, polymer-2.x

I'm writing a polymer app and have a service that is used by polymer elements. I want to test this service but can't figure out how.

Here's what I have in the service:

```
<script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<script src="../../web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>

<link rel="import" href="../test-service.html">

<script>
define('test-service', () => {
  class TestService {
    constructor(componentA, componentB) {
      this.componentA = componentA;
      this.componentB = componentB;
    }
  }
  return TestService;
});
</script>
```

How can I test this? If I try simply including the .html file I don't have access to TestService.

Comment: Have you tried `web-component-tester` ?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm using and where my trouble stems from. I updated my problem description accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. It all had to do with Polymer IMD and dependency injection. Defining a test suite looks different with it:

```
define('test-service-test', ['test-service'], (TestService) => {
    let testServiceInstance = new TestService(1, 2);

    test('basic test', function(){
        assert.equal(testServiceInstance.componentA, 1);
        assert.equal(testServiceInstance.componentB, 2);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the full html of an example test. Basically add your test-service tag via `test-fixture` and then see if it work appropriately.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>test-service test</title>

    <script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <script src="../../web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="../test-service.html">
</head>
<body>

<test-fixture id="BasicTestFixture">
    <template>
        <test-service></test-service>
    </template>
</test-fixture>

<script>
    suite('test-service', function() {

        test('instantiating the element with default properties works', function() {
            let testService = fixture('BasicTestFixture');
            assert.equal(testService.apiUrl, 'http://myapi.domain.com');
            // possible something like
            // let addResult = testService.addElement(...);
            // assert.equals(addResult, '{"result": "success"}');
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```